# Glassfish directory mappings: resources are cached by glassfish

Tags: image, upload, glassfish

I use the external resources mapping by glassfish for storing user uploaded images (sun-web.xml):

```
<property name="downloadroot" value="from=/downloaded dir=c:\glassfishv3\downloads"/>
```

I store uploaded images to this directory. The first download is ok, the image is shown at the address **server:8080/downloaded/image_13.png**. But when the users uploads another file and replaces the image (it is really replaced in file system) the GF doesn't show new image, but the old one. Event restart and osgi-cache/generated clean doesn't help! That's very misleading and hope anyone could help me with this issue..

Comment: Hi bitec, are you sure that not the browser caches the image?

Comment: +1 to MattHandy's suggestion.  Changing the content of media URLs is always problematic.  It's better to design the application to change to a new URL if something will be updated regularly.

Comment: thanks, guys, just posted the reason for this. I agree, that browser caches the image, even with Meta no-cache and expires parameters... But it's not for current situation, the reason was Jrebel - I posted the answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, the issue was in JRebel! I spent the whole day, and finally found the issue! So, if anyone meets with it, the reciept to fix is to include the gf virtual path to rebel.xml like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<application>
    <classpath>     
        <dir name="${myproject.root}\target\classes" />
    </classpath>
    <web>
        <link target="">
            <dir name="${myproject.root}\src\main\webapp" />
        </link>
        <link target="">
            <dir name="C:\glassfish3.1" />
        </link>
    </web>
</application>
```

Comment: Is it a copy-paste error that you have `glassfishv3` in sun-web.xml and `glassfish3.1` in rebel.xml?

Comment: Yes, just a typo. Use the same location in both configurations.